# How to Set-Cookie to all fileDownlink, not only one link by javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

```js
let cookieJar = request.jar();                                         
cookieJar.setCookie(`PHPSESSID=a; path=/; domain=`, 'http://www')

let options = {
    jar: cookieJar,
    method: 'GET',
    url: fileLink,
    headers: {
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.1'
    }
};
```

Is there any way to put it in expires info to Set-Cookie?

The site Set-Cookie results are these.

1. Date: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 06:27:24 GMT
2. Set-Cookie: e1192aefb64683cc97abb83c71057733=c3ViMDFfMDk%3D; expires=Wed, 13-Mar-2019 06:27:24 GMT; path=/

I wanted to Set-Cookie to all fileLink, but it doesn't work.

Comment: page links are http://www.jbba.kr/bbs/board.php?bo_table=sub01_09&wr_id=65

Comment: i fixed them!!could u checked them?